# increase the limit of record in csv download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have more than 50K records in database but when I download a csv from active admin it gives me just 10K. I have googled the solutions and got that there is limit in the method named max_csv_records in

**lib/active_admin/resource_controller/collection.rb**

is there some way from which I can override this and increase the limit ?

Here's the gist I got https://gist.github.com/3177995 but can you guys tell me how can I use this code ? It would be much better if I can add something in active admin initializer

Comment: does it not work if you add that code into a new file in the initializers? something like `config/initializers/csv_limit_override.rb`

Comment: yes it didn't work, i have made my own filter that will send csv to user in the provided email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is monkey patch for increasing export record limit https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/346

Answer (score 2):

Just for future googlers. My fix (working for the current Master 1.0.0pre) is to add the following to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module DataAccess
      # needed for current active admin master
      def max_per_page
        30_000
      end

      def per_page
        return 30_000 if %w(text/csv application/xml application/json).include?(request.format)

        return max_per_page if active_admin_config.paginate == false

        @per_page || active_admin_config.per_page
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Replace the max as needed. This works for csv, xml and json downloads.